# How can I remove numbers at the end of words?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove numbers from a string which is just placed after a word without any space. eg:

```
'Senku Ishigami is charecter from a manga series98 onging since 2017.'
```

should be:

```
'Senku Ishigami is charecter from a manga series onging since 2017.'
```

I could remove detect the numbers with a regex `'[a-z]+[0-9]+'`, But when I can't understand how can I remove it. I tried to remove it by just writing `'[a-z]'`, as I thought it would work, but it is just printing `'[a-z]'` as a string .

Here is the code:

```
import re

text ='Senku Ishigami is charecter from a manga series98 onging since 2017.'
text = re.sub(r'[a-z]+[0-9]+', '[a-z]', text)
print(text)
```

output:

```
Senku Ishigami is charecter from a manga [a-z] onging since 2017.
```

Comment: `re.sub(r'([a-z]+)(\d+)', r'\1', text)` ?

Comment: Could you please let know what output you expect for a `"Abc ab12cde567 ab68"` string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
import re

text ='Senku Ishigami is charecter from a manga series98 onging since 2017.'
text = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])\d+\b', '', text)
print(text) # => Senku Ishigami is charecter from a manga series onging since 2017.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mjActJ/1/) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VaWMeE).

**Regex details**

- `(?<=[a-z])` - a location immediately preceded with a lowercase ASCII letter
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\b` - word boundary (the digits will only be matched at the end of a word).

Answer (score 1):

You might also use a capturing group capturing only a single char before matching 1+ digits.

In the replacement using group 1 using `\1`

```
([a-z])\d+\b
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hYPZE2/1%5D)

```
import re

text ='Senku Ishigami is charecter from a manga series98 onging since 2017.'
text = re.sub(r'([a-z])\d+\b', r'\1', text)
print(text)
```

Output

```
Senku Ishigami is charecter from a manga series onging since 2017.
```